# How to achieve a custom image keyword search for my website?

Tags: html, image, search

I would like to provide a keyword search on my website that displays a list/grid of images that are related to the searched keyword.

I have been trying to find the best way to implement this into my website. Any standard search bar type of implementation doesn't really give me what I'd like. Would I have to create something from scratch? I'm knowledgeable in html and css but I don't really know anything about php, etc. So anything too complex, I might not be able to do and I'd like to not buy a service if possible.

I'm not sure if I'm needing to work with variables somehow? Or if I can create search results based on alt text? For example, an image has an alt text of "sunset beach" and the user searches "beach" and that image becomes one of the results and displays the image - not just the link to the image.

All of my images are through url. I do not store these images as files.
The images are formatted as `<a href="linktooriginalimagepage.com"><img src="theimage.com" alt="this is an image"></a>` in tables on multiple pages.

I don't really need a full search system. I just need a search bar that displays nothing but images on the page. Just a pointer in the right direction for this type of idea would be really helpful if anyone has any. I feel silly for asking but I've been researching for hours and not really finding the right solution. Thank you.

Update** To clarify, my site has multiple pages - each one belonging to a specific artist. Each artist will have images of the same thing (landscape images, school images, beach images) and The goal is to display any images of the same kind from multiple artists to one page mixed together.

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried the custom google search engine (but this didn't work at all, not even normal results so I'm not sure if this could be the solution if it actually worked - I'm waiting for feedback from the hosting site), I've tried some search widgets on other hosting sites in case one worked and I could just go use that host instead but they only display text with links to the right place. I've found some tutorials for really complex search systems that I don't need but nothing specific to what I want yet. I don't know if I need a traditional search engine for this - hoping to find an alternative

Answer (score 0):

**you can do this with ease with javascript;** 
there are multiple options for this case;
1. read the searchable data from exif; best if you change the pictures a lot and exporting them from lightroom or similar; 
2. create a file with the tags you want to search through; 
3. without js (just a bodge): use invisible text and strg+f;

Comment: I'm wondering if a js function would be sufficient enough (I'm working with numerous pages). Think it's possible with something equivalent getImagesByAlt(userinput) and a for loop to go through the images within the site by alt tags?

Comment: sure, this would be possible :)

Answer (score 0):

A very basic solution would be to create a dictionary to map alt texts to the image URLs.

```
const index = {
  'yellow rose flower': 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png',
  'tree and blue sky': 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.jpg',
  'mountains and blue sky': 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.webp'
}
```

Including this in a JavaScript file will negate the need for server-side code and a database. A static server will be enough. When a user types in a search term, you simply search the keys in the index for a partial match.

This presents a number of problems. If I type in the letter 'e', immediately all results are displayed. What if I only want results for whole words? I could certainly check this using JavaScript. And what if I type in 'sky blue' instead of 'blue sky'? Hmmm. Let's create a larger index, where each word is mapped to an array of results.

```
const img1 = 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.jpg';
const img2 = 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.webp';
const index = {
  'blue': [img1, img2],
  'mountain': [img2],
  'sky': [img1, img2],
  'tree': [img1]
}
```

This is a very basic [inverted index](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/a-first-take-at-building-an-inverted-index-1.html). Notice that I've eliminated the [stop word](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/dropping-common-terms-stop-words-1.html) *'and'*. I've also included the key *'mountain'* instead of *'mountains'*. This is called [stemming](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html).

For a more efficient solution you will need to learn about server-side coding as well as databases. For learning more about techniques used by search engines, the Stanford [Information Retrieval](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/information-retrieval-book.html) book is an excellent resource that is available for free. See if you can improve on the sample below.

```js
const index = {
  'yellow rose flower': 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png',
  'tree and blue sky': 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.jpg',
  'mountains and blue sky': 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.webp'
}

const searchbox = document.getElementById('searchbox');
const results = document.getElementById('results');

// In the HTML, oninput="search()" ensures this function is called
// every time a user types into the searchbox
function search(){
  clearContents(results); // remove previous results
  const searchTerm = searchbox.value.toLowerCase();
  
  // search the index for matching terms
  for(const key in index){
    if(key.includes(searchTerm) && searchTerm != ''){
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = index[key];
      results.appendChild(img);
    }
  }
}

function clearContents(elem){
  while(elem.firstChild){
    elem.removeChild(elem.firstChild);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="searchbox" type="text" oninput="search()">

<div id='results'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this as a solution, though I could see it taking a very long time because I'll be listing hundreds and hundreds of images, if not thousands at some point